# Always 404 error on my front-end magento 1.9.3.4

Tags: magento-1.9, htaccess

I put my site online in a hidden directory www.mydomain.or/test/magento/
with .htacces on my folder test

I put the url not secure = mydomain.or/test/magento/ 
And url secure = mydomain.or/test/magento/ 
with http:// before :)

I re-index my magento afterwards.
When I access the admin part of magento with 
 http://mydomain.or/test/magento/index.php/admin, it works

By cons for the front-end I always page not found (404) while I type
 http://mydomain.or/test/magento/.
I also tried it mydomain.or/test/magento/index.php

thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0):

Please try to rename var folder and check.

Comment: I just do it is always the same...

Is there a condition to add the file .htaccess ?

Comment: Did you configure  your local.xml properly?